# Changing climate grid values by adding decimal point numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, reclassify, climate

I have climate grids (based on climate data from 1961-1991) which I have converted from ascii to raster in ArcGis 10.2.2. The temperature is in degrees celsius. I want to alter the temperature values to incorporate future climate changes in the temperature. I want to alter the whole grid by the same number, but the numbers I want to add to the grid are 0.3 or 0.8 etc, therefore reclassify is not possible.  I do not have another layer or grid, I just want to add numbers to the current grid values, for example, all grid values + 0.3°C. Would this be possible using the raster calculator and how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the spatial analysts [PLUS tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/plus.htm) to add 0.3 or 0.8 to your climate grid. If you read the help file (syntax section) the second grid which you add to your input grid can actually be a constant and not just another grid. So putting 0.3 into that will add 0.3 to all the cells in your input raster.